# How to setup Ampache

Tags: server, apache2, php

How exactly do you configure [Ampache](http://ampache.org) to run on a clean Apache install?

I am trying to manually configure this because `sudo apt-get install ampache` fails to do so properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ampache-3.3.3.5-dfsg1-1 will be included into the Hardy release of Ubuntu and is available for download.

Ampache-3.4.1 will be included into the Intrepid release of Ubuntu and is available for download.

Due to Debian Release Freeze Ampache-3.4.3-1 will not be in the Lenny release. However a Feature Freeze Exception was granted for Ampache-3.4.3-0ubuntu1 to be included into Intrepid.

Due to a lintian error, Ampache-3.4.3-0ubuntu1 now depends on libjs-prototype. libjs-prototype is only available in Intrepid and Lenny. Currently libjs-prototype is not in the Hardy archive unless it is backported. So what this means is that Ampache-3.4.3-0ubuntu1 will not install on Hardy or Etch due to Unmet Dependencies.

The maintainer has been kind enough to make a version of Ampache-3.4.3-0ubuntu1 for Hardy and Etch. These are not official packages so please do not file bug reports against them, contact me directly.

The Hardy/Etch version of Ampache-3.4.3-0ubuntu1 can be found here

There is also the Ampache-Themes-3.3.3.5a-1 themes package available in the Hardy archives. Sorry, for those folks using Ampache-3.4 additional themes are not yet available due to the fact that Ampache-3.4 is still in development.

Now open a terminal and type

sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install ampache mysql-server-5.0 phpmyadmin

Set up a mysql user account with root privileges

Point your browser to http://localhost/ampache orhttp://your.ip.address/ampache and follow the install instruction.

There is a very good install guide located on the Wiki or atAmpache For Debian And Ubuntu.